# Fancy cover page

Tags: lyx, titles

Can I get help creating a [fancy cover page like this one](http://curry.virginia.edu/uploads/resourceLibrary/17_Castleman_All_or_Nothing.pdf):

[image]

I have the [logo in an SVG file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/936wxivh692wvmb/UVA_Rotunda_Logo.svg):

[image]

PS: I'm using LyX on Ubuntu

---

I have the fancy footer working, but no hope of doing the rest by myself.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{curry}{RGB}{29,109,136}
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\color{black} \thepage}
\patchcmd{\@fancyfoot}{\rlap}{\color{curry}\rlap}{}{}
\makeatother
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{black} {\hfill \thepage}\\
\color{curry} \fontsize{10}{11} \selectfont CEPWC Working Paper Series No. 13 July 2013.\\
Available at \url{ http://curry.virginia.edu/research/centers/cepwc/publications}.\\
Curry School of Education | Frank Batten School of Leadership and Public Policy | University of Virginia}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{Martinez, Lessons from a MOOC}
```

Comment: Please be more specific, show what you’ve tried and what didn’t work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: On top of the very good advice provided in the comments above, have you tried to ask the author for the class he used? If you're lucky it's a publicly available class provided by University of Virginia...

Comment: @AlexisPigeon The original document was made in MS Word :_(

Comment: @KevinC Is there a better place where I could ask for this type of help?

Comment: @doncherry My latex/lyx knowledge is not advance enough to make something like that, sorry for not having a reproducible example.

Comment: I think, __maybe__, http://www.latex-community.org/forum is not that strict on what type of questions are accepted.

Comment: Most of that is just centered text with different size and color. To center text, right click --> paragraph settings, to change size and color, select text, right click --> Text style --> Customized. To insert horizontal lines, Insert --> Formatting --> Horizontal line. Edit: 'Left' in the paragraph settings means a ragged right margin (as in the Acknowledgements), 'Justified' is straight margins (as in the Abstract).

Comment: @marczellm: Though there is no restriction in types of questions, they also don't like questions that sound like "Do this for me" without any trace of own efforts. What they like is a self-contained and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (as nearly everybody who tries to help).

Comment: @Ignacio You'll also need the Calibri, Minion Pro and Myriad Pro fonts.